# Outlook api. How to search emails with oauth token?

Tags: oauth, outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Is there any working and complete code samples that demonstrate how to work with hotmail api?

For example I've already made for gmail api with web application:

- oAuth
- search mail by uuid inside mail body
- get Message Content
- get Message Attachment
- some processing code

Now I need to integrate hotmail. 
done only:

- oAuth with scope `https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read`

That code samples that I found in official documentation doesn't shows how to pass oauth token - thats why have a lot of questions

Share some links that will help me, please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use the [Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/) to read and search emails. It works for work, school and personal Microsoft accounts (hotmail, live, outlook.com, etc).

Since you already have an access token, just pass it through with an `Authorization` header. More information about using access tokens with the Microsoft Graph can be found in [their documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/auth_overview).

Authorization: Bearer `[Access Token]`

For searching email, try the following query:
`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$search="hello world"`. If you're trying to search for emails in a different user's mail, try:

`GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages?$search=foobar`

I also recommend trying the [Microsoft Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/graph/graph-explorer) since it has sample queries for Outlook Mail. To show the Outlook samples, click the `show more samples` link.  Also, clicking the icon to the right of each query will bring you to the documentation page for that sample.

[image]